# Issues with .net gzip decompression stream

Tags: .net, compression, gzip

What could be wrong with those set of methods?

```
        byte[] bytes;

        using (var memory_stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var gzip_stream = new GZipStream(memory_stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            var buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello nurse!");
            gzip_stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            bytes = memory_stream.ToArray();
        }

        int total_read = 0;

        using (var input_stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var gzip_stream = new GZipStream(input_stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        {
            int read;
            var buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((read = gzip_stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
                total_read += read;
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(bytes);
        Debug.WriteLine(total_read);
```

The gzipStr is a valid Gzipped Stream (I could compress it successfully with GzipStream() Compress).

Why is total_read always 0??? is gzip stream decompressing my stream? am I doing something wrong?

What am I doing wrong here???!!!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to flush. :)  Note that Encoding.Default should not generally be used in production.  In the below, replace it with Encoding.UTF8 (or whatever's appropriate).  Finally, of course, the below santiy-check only works if everything fits in a single buffer.  But now you should get the idea.

kementeus indicated my previous code here didn't help, so below is the exact code I used:

```
public class GzipBug
{
    public static void Main(String[] a)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer;

    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        using (var memory_stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var gzip_stream = new GZipStream(memory_stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            buffer = encoding.GetBytes("Hello nurse!");
            gzip_stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        gzip_stream.Flush();
        bytes = memory_stream.ToArray();
        }

        int total_read = 0;

        using (var input_stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var gzip_stream = new GZipStream(input_stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        {
        int read;
            buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((read = gzip_stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
        total_read += read;
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(buffer, 0, total_read));
        Debug.WriteLine(total_read);

    }
}
```

It is compiled with:
    gmcs -d:DEBUG -langversion:linq -debug+ GzipBug.cs
and run as:
    MONO_TRACE_LISTENER=Console.Out GzipBug.exe

(you can remove the MONO_TRACE_LISTENER bit)

Comment: Ok, I got your point with gzip stream Flush and use Encoding.Default / Encoding.UTF8... But my issue was never related to the gzip compression, it works fine...

I did your modifications but total read _stills_ 0

So the main issue persists

Comment: I just posted the exact code I'm using. If you take out the Flush, it gives 0, if you put it in, it gives 12. I agree the Encoding.UTF8 is a side issue, but it's always worth paying attention to encoding.